# Do something upon accepting an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute some code when an alert is accept by the user, I know about this:

```
if(confirm("Go to the next step"))  
  {
    document.write("accepted");
  }  
else{  
   document.write("rejected");  
}
```

the point is I want the box to have only one button like the normal alert, and by clicking it I can execute something.

Comment: simple if you want only one button and forcefully ask the user to accept the `alert` then use `alert` box rather than `confirm`.

Comment: What do mean by displaying only one button and right the code to check user has accepted or not. He will have to forcefully accept it, thats the only option for user.

Comment: actually you are already executing *something* ... `document.write(...)` is your action

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `alert` command in javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

I believe any line of javascript code that is placed after the `alert` line is executed after the alert window closes.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever statement you put after `alert` will be executed when user clicks on okay.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvPsx/1/)
And when you say alert user don't have any other choice other than clicking on okay.

Answer (score 0):

- `alert()` - One button (OK)　Try a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/3R3yV/
- `confirm()` - Two buttons (OK, cancel)
- `prompt()` - Two buttons + one input field (OK, cancel)

For other buttons, you might want to try out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com).
[image]

> jQuery User Interface does let developers to create custom dialogs.